# Process for comparing two datasets

Tags: matlab, dataset, compare, signal-processing, similarity

I have two datasets at the time (in the form of vectors) and I plot them on the same axis to see how they relate with each other, and I specifically note and look for places where both graphs have a similar shape (i.e places where both have seemingly positive/negative gradient at approximately the same intervals). Example:

[image]

So far I have been working through the data graphically but realize that since the amount of the data is so large plotting each time I want to check how two sets correlate graphically it will take far too much time.

Are there any ideas, scripts or functions that might be useful in order to automize this process somewhat?

Comment: depending on the nature of the data, I would recommend doing frequency analysis using the FFT function. (Be sure to understand how to scale your data correctly in the FFT domain!)

alternatively using something as simply as mean squared error could be useful. If you can say more about the nature and origin of the data we might be able to give you some better advice.

Comment: @thron Note that to get what he wants, he needs to find similarity in phase not just frequency between the two signals.  That's not trivial.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you have to think about is the nature of the criteria you want to apply to establish the similarity. There is a wide variety of ways to measure similarity and the more precisely you can describe what you want for "similar" to mean in your problem the easiest it will be to implement it regardless of the programming language.

Having said that, here is some of the thing you could look at :

- correlation of the two datasets
- difference of the derivative of the datasets (but I don't think it would be robust enough)
- spectral analysis as mentionned by @thron of three
- etc. ...

Knowing the origin of the datasets and their variability can also help a lot in formulating robust enough algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Call your two vectors A and B.

1) (Optional) Smooth your data either with a simple averaging filter (Matlab 'smooth'), or the 'filter' command.  This will get rid of local changes in velocity ("gradient") that appear to be essentially noise (as in the ascending component of the red trace.

2) Differentiate both A and B.  Now you are directly representing the velocity of each vector (Matlab 'diff').

3) Add the two differentiated vectors together (element-wise).  Call this C.

4) Look for all points in C whose absolute value is above a certain threshold (you'll have to eyeball the data to get a good idea of what this should be).  Points above this threshold indicate highly similar velocity.

5) Now look for where a high positive value in C is followed by a high negative value, or vice versa.  In between these two points you will have similar curves in A and B.

Note: a) You could do the smoothing after step 3 rather than after step 1. b) Re 5), you could have a situation in which a 'hill' in your data is at the edge of the vector and so is 'cut in half', and the vectors descend to baseline before ascending in the next hill.  Then 5) would misidentify the hill as coming between the initial descent and subsequent ascent.  To avoid this, you could also require that the points in A and B in between the two points of velocity similarity have high absolute values.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a very interesting route!